# capture browser/webpage data of post event in mvc c#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post, browser, response

i am calling a url programmatically through MVC application and the response i get is on browser as below

[image]

Is there any way i can capture / copy this data programmatically and store in my db.

Below is my code in index page.

```
@model DataTransfere.Models.XMLBasedData 
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Index"; }
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.onload = function () {
                $("#btn_submit").trigger("click");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="http://172.18.1.57:8080/webdesktop/APIExecutor" method="POST">
            @{ string a = ViewBag.xml_data; }
            @Html.TextArea("inXml", a, new { name = "inXml" } )
            <input type="submit" value="register" id="btn_submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is controller code

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.xml_data = "<?xml version='1.0'?><WMConnect_Input><Option>WMConnect</Option><EngineName>iflidmsuat</EngineName><ApplicationInfo>172.18.1.57</ApplicationInfo><Participant>  <Name>test1234</Name>   <Password>test1234</Password>   <Scope></Scope> <UserExist>Y</UserExist>    <Locale>en-US</Locale>  <ParticipantType>U</ParticipantType></Participant></WMConnect_Input>";  
    return View();
}
```

Through viewbag data is passed and url is hit, but how i can capture data that displays on my browser page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will need to create a web request for reading it, something like:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://172.18.1.57:8080/webdesktop/APIExecutor") as HttpWebRequest; 
var response = request.GetResponse();

Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

var result =  readStream.ReadToEnd();
```

Further once you have the data, you can use XML libraries to read and process

Comment: do i need to put this in Controller or call url separately through code above .

Comment: Well, you need not to pass Post in View, you can do complete implementation in Controller and get the data in response.